# Getting name of shapefile from its path with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, file-path

I am making a Plugin and I uploaded my shp file using my shp file path, how can I extract the name of the file from it?

Example: D:/Qgis files/sub_folderName/FileName.shp

I want to save the FileName in a string as FileName using PyQGIS.

Comment: It is a pure Python problem without geospatial component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing the "os" library of python will provide the solution to this problem. You can use the following command to extract the filename from the complete path:

```
import os
os.path.basename("Write the path here").split(".")[0]
```

---

`os.path.basename()` extracts the filename from the given path. So, in your example case, it would be FileName.shp. Then, I split this FileName.shp with "." using the split function. So, the split function will return a list with the filename and its extension. Then, I used indexing "[0]" to extract the filename from that list. Hope I'm able to explain it properly.